# Lawnchair + Android + PhoneGap working, but not persistent

Tags: android, cordova, lawnchair

This is my first attempt at using [Lawnchair](http://brian.io/lawnchair/). I was able to get a simple save/get example working, but the get only seems to work as long as it is within the same application launch. On subsequent app launches, it fails to find the object I have previously saved, so it appears it is not persistent.

I understand that 'DOM' is the default adapter for Lawnchair, but I was under the impression that DOM storage was persistent. Any ideas as to why it is not working for me? I have tested this on a Win7 machine running Chrome, and also on an Android device using PhoneGap. Again, it works within the scope of a single app launch, but the objects stored do not persist in subsequent app launches. My code is below. To test the Get on subsequent launches, I simply commented out the instantiation and save parts.

**UPDATE:** I attempted to use the [Google Gears sqlite adapter](http://brian.io/lawnchair/adapters/), but when debugging, it got hung up on the first line where I instantiate, and never moved past that point. This all seems so simple, yet can't actually get it to work. What gives?

```
new Lawnchair({
adapter: "dom",
name: "ce-app-db"
}, function () {
this.nuke();
});

Lawnchair({ name: 'ce-app-db' }, function () {
    alert('storage open - save');
    this.save({ key: 'insps', value: msg });
});

Lawnchair({ name: 'ce-app-db' }, function () {
    alert('storage open - get');
    this.get('insps', function (obj) {
    if (obj) {
        var index = 0;
        $.each(obj.value, function (i, item) {
            if (item != null) {
                index++;
            }
        });
        alert(index + ' cases found');
    }
    else {
        alert('cases not found');
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Your setup code (on line 4) when loading the database is `this.nuke()`, so every time you try to load the database, you delete all of the entries in it.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, really not sure what I was doing wrong, but after re-writing my code to be more like [this example](https://github.com/dhavaln/cordova-examples/blob/master/android-cordova-lawnchair/assets/www/index.html), my data is now persistent between app launches.